fresco-2.2.0.pom error started suddenly on a stable react native 63 project
Have cleared gradle and my node_modules.
I have tried many versions like FLIPPER_VERSION=0.191.1 and tried many other things but errors like

Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1.
or

Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.191.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/Users/vikas/.m2/repository/com/facebook/flipper/flipper-fresco-plugin/0.191.1/flipper-fresco-plugin-0.191.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/flipper/flipper-fresco-plugin/0.191.1/flipper-fresco-plugin-0.191.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/flipper/flipper-fresco-plugin/0.191.1/flipper-fresco-plugin-0.191.1.pom
       - https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo/com/facebook/flipper/flipper-fresco-plugin/0.191.1/flipper-fresco-plugin-0.191.1.pom
       - file:/Users/vikas/projects/aurum/mobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/flipper/flipper-fresco-plugin/0.191.1/flipper-fresco-plugin-0.191.1.pom
       - file:/Users/vikas/projects/aurum/mobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/facebook/flipper/flipper-fresco-plugin/0.191.1/flipper-fresco-plugin-0.191.1.pom
       - file:/Users/vikas/projects/aurum/mobile/node_modules/detox/Detox-android/com/facebook/flipper/flipper-fresco-plugin/0.191.1/flipper-fresco-plugin-0.191.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/flipper/flipper-fresco-plugin/0.191.1/flipper-fresco-plugin-0.191.1.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/facebook/flipper/flipper-fresco-plugin/0.191.1/flipper-fresco-plugin-0.191.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

not able to resolve this strange errors. please suggest
